# Check if list is empty

Tags: isblank

I have to check whether a `list<Order>` is empty or `null`.I can use `isEmpty()` to check this.

But Can I use `isBlank()` with `list<Order>` to check.

Comment: I was thinking the same.Thanks for the comments guys.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the above

a common pattern I see in posts is this:

```
if (!myListOfSobjects.isEmpty())
  insert myListOfSobjects;  // do some DML -- could be update, delete, upsert too
```

this is all unnecessary - just do the DML; if list is empty, SFDC does nothing. Code is cleaner

```
  insert myListOfSobjects;  // do some DML -- could be update, delete, upsert too
```

another pattern sometimes seen in posts is this

```
if (myListOfObjects.size() > 0) {
  for (myObject m : myListOfObjects) {..}
```

this too is unnecessary; just do as shown below; if the list is empty, no iterations are done

```
for (myObject m : myListOfObjects) {..}
```

Answer (score 3):

No. `isBlank` is a Formula operator which can be used to check if a field value is blank or not.

so, you can use only one of the below:

```
list != null  //Null check
list.isEmpty()  //Check if its blank
list.size() == 0  //Compare size
```

Comment: also `String.isBlank()` is useful for testing if a string is null or empty string

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method called isBlank supported by the List Class. Please refer the available methods of for List [**here**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm).

To check if list is empty you can either use

```
list.isEmpty()
```

or

```
list.size() == 0
```